# multiple projects and entities in Hibernate 4 : entity is not mapped

Tags: hibernate

I need some help with a strange error : "Fabricationfolder is not mapped".

Here is the context :
I Have a project "war" which includes a library "jar". Both of them has entity on two separated schema MariaDB.
I cannot change anything to the jar because, it's used by other projects.
I'm using the same hibernate version for both : 4.1.7 and spring 4.

For some reasons, I need to link some entities of my war to the jar entities. In order to add attributes to jar's entity, I decided to extends some entities of the jar into my war.
Is it a good way?

When I'm launching the web, app, the first request on Fabricationfolder fails with this error.

Here ares the configuration :

Schema : 
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS sampledb
        CHARACTER SET latin1
        COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

```
USE sampledb;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fabricationfolder (
  id_folder INT(11) NOT NULL,
  id_product_type INT(11) NOT NULL,
  folder_number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  customer_code VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  customer_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  brand VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  creation_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  bat VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  grouped VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  fabrication_limit_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
  classification VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  observation VARCHAR(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  status VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  height DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  flag_height INT(1) NOT NULL,
  width DECIMAL(7, 2) DEFAULT NULL,
  flag_width INT(1) NOT NULL,
  intermediate_code VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  date_update DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  user_update VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  assignment VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_user_commercial INT(11) NOT NULL,
  id_group_commercial INT(11) NOT NULL,
  id_group_scheduling INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_group_pilotage INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_folder),
  INDEX id_product_type (id_product_type)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 1365
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE schema security;

CREATE TABLE security.group (grp_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, grp_name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (grp_id));
CREATE TABLE security.user (usr_id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, usr_creation TIMESTAMP, usr_email VARCHAR(128), usr_enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL, usr_expiration TIMESTAMP, usr_firstname VARCHAR(50), usr_lastname VARCHAR(50), usr_modification TIMESTAMP, usr_password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, usr_login VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (usr_id));
```

Entity Fabricationfolder in war, package com.sp.sfc.business.model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fabricationfolder")
public class Fabricationfolder implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int idFolder;

    private ProductType productType; 

    private String folderNumber;

    private String customerCode;

    private String customerName;

    private String brand;

    private Date creationDate;

    private String bat;

    private String grouped;

    private Date endDate;

    private String classification;

    private String observation;

    private String status;

    private Double height;

    private Double width;

    private boolean flagHeight;

    private boolean flagWidth;

    private String intermediateCode;

    private Date dateUpdate;

    private String userUpdate;

    private String assignment;

    private User userCommercial;

    private Group groupCommercial;

    private Group groupScheduling;

    private Group groupPilotage;

    private List<Publication> publications = new ArrayList<Publication>();

    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();

    public Fabricationfolder() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_folder", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getIdFolder() {
        return this.idFolder;
    }

    public void setIdFolder(int idFolder) {
        this.idFolder = idFolder;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product_type", nullable = false)
    public ProductType getProductType() {
        return this.productType;
    }

    public void setProductType(ProductType productType) {
        this.productType = productType;
    }

    @Column(name = "folder_number", nullable = false, length = 15)
    public String getFolderNumber() {
        return this.folderNumber;
    }

    public void setFolderNumber(String folderNumber) {
        this.folderNumber = folderNumber;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_code", nullable = false, length = 15)
    public String getCustomerCode() {
        return this.customerCode;
    }

    public void setCustomerCode(String customerCode) {
        this.customerCode = customerCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "customer_name", nullable = false, length = 32)
    public String getCustomerName() {
        return this.customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    @Column(name = "brand", nullable = false, length = 32)
    public String getBrand() {
        return this.brand;
    }

    public void setBrand(String brand) {
        this.brand = brand;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return this.creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "bat", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getBat() {
        return this.bat;
    }

    public void setBat(String bat) {
        this.bat = bat;
    }

    @Column(name = "grouped", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getGrouped() {
        return this.grouped;
    }

    public void setGrouped(String grouped) {
        this.grouped = grouped;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "fabrication_limit_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getEndDate() {
        return this.endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date fabricationLimitDate) {
        this.endDate = fabricationLimitDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "classification", length = 15)
    public String getClassification() {
        return this.classification;
    }

    public void setClassification(String classification) {
        this.classification = classification;
    }

    @Column(name = "observation", length = 250)
    public String getObservation() {
        return this.observation;
    }

    public void setObservation(String observation) {
        this.observation = observation;
    }

    @Column(name = "status", length = 30)
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Column(name = "height")
    public Double getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    @Column(name = "height")
    public void setHeight(Double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Column(name = "width", precision = 7)
    public Double getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }

    public void setWidth(Double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Column(name = "intermediate_code", length = 15)
    public String getIntermediateCode() {
        return this.intermediateCode;
    }

    public void setIntermediateCode(String intermediateCode) {
        this.intermediateCode = intermediateCode;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_update", length = 10)
    public Date getDateUpdate() {
        return this.dateUpdate;
    }

    public void setDateUpdate(Date dateUpdate) {
        this.dateUpdate = dateUpdate;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_update", length = 20)
    public String getUserUpdate() {
        return this.userUpdate;
    }

    public void setUserUpdate(String userUpdate) {
        this.userUpdate = userUpdate;
    }

    @Column(name = "assignment", length = 15)
    public String getAssignment() {
        return this.assignment;
    }

    public void setAssignment(String assignment) {
        this.assignment = assignment;
    }

    @OrderBy("publicationDate ASC")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fabricationfolder")
    public List<Publication> getPublications() {
        return this.publications;
    }

    public void setPublications(List<Publication> publications) {
        this.publications = publications;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @OrderBy("creationDate ASC")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fabricationfolder")
    public  List<Element> getElements() {
        return this.elements;
    }

    public void setElements(List<Element> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user_commercial", nullable = true, referencedColumnName= "usr_id")
    public User getUserCommercial() {
        return userCommercial;
    }

    public void setUserCommercial(User userCommercial) {
        this.userCommercial = userCommercial;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_group_commercial", nullable = true, referencedColumnName= "grp_id")
    public Group getGroupCommercial() {
        return groupCommercial;
    }

    public void setGroupCommercial(Group groupCommercial) {
        this.groupCommercial = groupCommercial;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_group_scheduling", nullable = true, referencedColumnName= "grp_id")
    public Group getGroupScheduling() {
        return groupScheduling;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fabricationfolder")
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setGroupScheduling(Group groupScheduling) {
        this.groupScheduling = groupScheduling;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_group_pilotage", nullable = true, referencedColumnName= "grp_id")
    public Group getGroupPilotage() {
        return groupPilotage;
    }

    public void setGroupPilotage(Group groupPilotage) {
        this.groupPilotage = groupPilotage;
    }

    @Column(name = "flag_height", nullable = false)
    public boolean isFlagHeight() {
        return flagHeight;
    }

    public void setFlagHeight(boolean flagHeight) {
        this.flagHeight = flagHeight;
    }

    @Column(name = "flag_width", nullable = false)
    public boolean isFlagWidth() {
        return flagWidth;
    }

    public void setFlagWidth(boolean flagWidth) {
        this.flagWidth = flagWidth;
    }
}
```

User and Group extends :

```
@Entity
public class User extends SPUser {

    public User(String login, String pass, String email) {
        super(login, pass, email);
    }

    public List<Group> getUserGroups(){
        List<Group> listGroup = new ArrayList<Group>();
        for(SPGroup agroup: getGroups()){
            listGroup.add((Group)agroup);
        }
        return listGroup;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Group extends SPGroup {

    public Group(String groupName) {
        super(groupName);
    }       

}
```

Entities User And Group of jar  package com.sfc.security.metier.impl :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="group", schema="security")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SPGroup implements Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "grp_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "grp_name", unique = true, nullable = false, length=150)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_user", schema="security", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "grp_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "usr_id", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<SPUser> users = new ArrayList<SPUser>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "childGroups")
    private List<SPGroup> parentGroups = new ArrayList<SPGroup>();
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "group_group", schema="security", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName="grp_id") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", 
                    nullable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName="grp_id") })
    private List<SPGroup> childGroups = new ArrayList<SPGroup>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=RoleTag.class ,mappedBy = "group", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<RoleTag> roleTags = new ArrayList<RoleTag>();
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity=PermissionTag.class, mappedBy = "group", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<PermissionTag> permissionTags = new ArrayList<PermissionTag>();

    ...
}

@Entity@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name="user", schema="security")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SPUser implements User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6335411953406117295L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "usr_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "usr_password", nullable = false, length=100)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "usr_login", unique=true, nullable = false, length=128)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "usr_enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "usr_expiration")
    private Date expirationDate;

    @Column(name = "usr_firstname", length=50)
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "usr_lastname", length=50)
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name = "usr_email", unique=true, length=128)
    private String email;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "usr_creation")
    private Date creationDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "usr_modification")
    private Date modificationDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
    private List<SPGroup> groups;

    ...
}
```

And the configuration for hibernate war :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.sp.sfc.business")
@PropertySource("classpath:properties/${environnement:prod}/application.properties")
public class WebBusinessConfig implements TransactionManagementConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public DataSource businessDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sampledb");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");

        return dataSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean businessSessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(businessDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.sp.sfc.business.model,com.sfc.security.metier.impl");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(hibernate.dialect, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put(hibernate.show_sql, "true");
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateBusinessTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(businessSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Override
    public PlatformTransactionManager annotationDrivenTransactionManager() {
        return hibernateBusinessTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

And jar configuration

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagersfcSecurity" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.sfc.security.repositories" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactorysfcSecurity" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManagersfcSecurity"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactorysfcSecurity" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourcesfcSecurity"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sfc.security.metier.impl" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
                <property name="showSql" value="false"/>            
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="$HibernateConfigurationsfcSecurity"/>
    </bean>

    <util:map id="HibernateConfigurationsfcSecurity" >
        <entry key="hibernate.generateDdl" value="false" />
        <entry key="hibernate.databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <entry key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
    </util:map>

    <bean   id="dataSourcesfcSecurity" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sampledb" />
        <property name="username" value="user" />
        <property name="password" value="pass" />
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagersfcSecurity" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactorysfcSecurity" />
    </bean>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check if your package is being scanned for entities in your configuration.

Comment: The scan packages in configuration contains the good package

Comment: In the jar project, the architecture use jpa and entitymanagerfactory and in the war project, it uses hibernate sessionfactory.
Is there a conflicting way?

Comment: That may not be good idea to use both entity manger and session in same application. Your jar configuration scans "com.sfc.security.repositories" package but your class "FabricationFolder" is in "com.sp.sfc.business.model"

Answer (score 0):

The error was there :

```
sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.sp.sfc.business.model,com.sfc.security.metier.impl").split(",");
```

split was missing.